# Binding to CustomControls issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm, custom-controls

I have a custom control that inherit from TextBox with dependcy property called State.
State is enum with 4 options {Mismatch, Wait, Ok, None}

The Generic looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomTextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="State" Value="Mismatch">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MismatchBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomTextBox}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorederBrush="{TemplateBinding BorederBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

I have class Named MyData with properties DataState, Sent, Recieved each property implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

In my main window i have the following row in the xaml:

```
<custom:CustomTextBox State="{Binding BindingData.DataState}" Text="{Binding BindedData.Sent}"/>
```

and in my view model i have field from type MyData that called BindedData and when user send some data the BindedData.Sent change and then if some logic occur the BindedData state change to Mismatch and the customTextBox background need to be in some color.

The problem is that the background not change its mean the binding of the state not working and also the text binding not working.

I know how the binding works and its work for me in other cases (not with custom controls) and here i also checked in debug and i saw that all going right so did i make something wrong with the customcontrol?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you set the background again from the main window? 
I have tried copy your code and it works perfectly , unless I set the background from the main window (since it overrides the style setters)